# css style remains after click

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have a simple test page with a single styled button. I'm using a:hover when you hover over the button. However, when you click the button the a:hover style remains until I click on something else. How would I fix this and why is this happening?

Thanks,
rod.

```
<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { }))
       { %>
    <div id="detailActions">
        <a href="#">Delete User</a>
    </div>
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

My CSS:

```
#detailActions
{
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    padding: 3px 0px 5px 0px;
}
#detailActions
{
    padding: 1px 7px 1px 7px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    background-color: #ADD8E6;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #003366;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

#detailActions a:hover, #detailActions a:active, #detailActions a:focus
{
    color: White;
    background-color: #00008B;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the `a:focus` which makes it look like the `a:hover` rule is activated. `a:focus` matches any link which is focused. When you click a link, it becomes focused.

Remove the `a:focus` rule and it should be fine.